# Strip/convert html artifacts from email html body in php/laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm using an IMAP package in laravel to get the bodies of emails, but I'm still getting a lot of HTML artifacts even after doing some stripping.

I'm using these functions right now:

```
        $styles_removed = preg_replace('/(<(script|style)\b[^>]*>).*?(<\/\2>)/is', "$1$3", $body);
        $fixed_body = strip_tags($styles_removed);
        $strip_body = utf8_decode($fixed_body);
        $formatted_body = preg_replace('/\s+|body {.*}/', ' ', $strip_body);
```

After doing this, I'm dumping `$formatted_body` and getting this example:

```
I?m trying to start a thread &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; Jon Doe &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp; Sales &amp;amp; Service &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;
```

Am I missing a function that I should be using on top of the existing ones that would convert the &amp and nbsp to their actual characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$formatted_body = 'I?m trying to start a thread &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp; Jon Doe &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp; Sales &amp;amp; Service &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;';

$content = preg_replace('/[^\S\r\n]+/',' ',trim(str_replace(['&nbsp;','&amp;'],[' ','&'],htmlspecialchars_decode($formatted_body ,ENT_QUOTES|ENT_COMPAT))));

echo $content;
```

Which result to

```
I?m trying to start a thread Jon Doe Sales & Service
```

I don't know why `?` is in the `single quotes`, it should `&apos;`